# jQuery/JavaScript alternative to VB.NET's smtp.Send

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I am trying to rewrite the Contact Us section of my web application, currently written in VB.Net, to using jQuery/JavaScript.

At present, all it contains is the email Subject, and body.. The mailTo address is defined in my VB.Net .CS file and web.config:

**VB.Net  .CS file:**

```
Dim FromPersonName As String = FromName.Text
Dim FromPersonEmail As String = FromEmail.Text
Dim ToAddress As String = "sales@myDomain.co.uk"

Dim mm As New MailMessage(FromEmail.Text, ToAddress)
mm.Subject = Subject.Text
mm.IsBodyHtml = False

Dim smtp As New SmtpClient
smtp.Send(mm)
```

**WebConfig:**

```
<system.net>
   <mailSettings>
      <smtp>
    <network host="mail.myDomain.co.uk" port="25" userName="xxxx" password="xxxx" />
  </smtp>
```

How would i go about converting above to using html/jquery javascript? Can i use my existing config file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to directly send via javascript.

What you need to do here is have javascript make an ajax post request to your asp webserver. If your doing vb.bet with webforms, you would make a new page that accepts the POST data and then proceeds to send the email.

Ideal flow is

User clicks send on contact us page --> Javascript stops full page post, and asynchronously POSTs data to server page --> server page sends email.

Comment: @mitusw16 - thanks, that kind of makes sense. Do you have an example i could follow at all, sorry am new to this.

Comment: I don't have any examples or know of any tuts that list that exact process with webforms and vb.net. It's a pretty light day at work today though, I'll try to whip something up and post it here.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this is a pretty basic example, but hopefully should give enough of an idea to point you in the right direction.

This is a mockup of a form on your contact us page. Note the id is form1

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    name<br />
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="email" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    email<br />
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="message" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    message<br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" /> 
</div>
</form>
```

On the same page, I wrote the following bit of javascript to catch the form submit event, and send the data via ajax instead of a full page postback. I used jquery 1.9.1

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#form1").submit(function (e) {
            console.log("hello");

            e.preventDefault();

            var formData = $("#form1").serialize();

            $.ajax({
                type:"POST", 
                data: formData, 
                url: "SendMail.ashx"
            }).done(function() {
                alert("Message sent!");
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

Now, You will need to add another item to your solution, a generic event handler. This is what the javascript is POSTing to, and what will actually send the email. Here is what mine looked like as an example

```
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Services

Public Class SendMail
Implements System.Web.IHttpHandler

Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
    'get post data from AJAX call
    Dim name As String = context.Request("name")
    Dim email As String = context.Request("email")
    Dim message As String = context.Request("message")

    'here you would put your email code

End Sub

ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
    Get
        Return False
    End Get
End Property

End Class
```

So the flow here is user loads contact page and fills out form --> submit button is clicked --> javascript catches and prevents full page post back and asynchronously posts form data to event handler --> sendmail.ashx page gets form data and actually sends the email.